# Read and Write any data structure to and from a file?

Tags: java, file, data-structures, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Below is the code I use to read and write HashMaps too and from a file. I'm wondering, is there anyway I can re-factor this code so that any data structure can be read in and wrote out? Rather than creating a new class for each data structure? I appreciate any help offered!

```
public class FileHandler {

    static ObjectOutputStream oos;
    static ObjectInputStream ois;


    public static void writeOut(HashMap p, File selection) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
      {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(selection));
        oos.writeObject(p);
        oos.close();
      }

      public static HashMap<String, Object> readIn(File selection) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
      {
          HashMap<String, Object> temp = null;
          ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(selection));
          temp = (HashMap<String, Object>) ois.readObject(); 
          ois.close();
        return temp;
      }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any Serializable `Object` you could do something like (also, I would use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)),

```
public static void writeOut(Object p, File selection)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(selection))) {
        oos.writeObject(p);
    }
}
```

and

```
public static Object readIn(File selection) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            selection))) {
        return ois.readObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change writeOut() method signature to

```
public static void writeOut(Serializable o, File selection) throws FileNotFoundException
```

and in readIn(File selection), use `Object temp` instead of `HashMap<String, Object> temp`

You might want to add some `instanceof` checks before doing an unchecked type conversion whenever you use readIn()